# Add Google Fonts to Primefaces Text Editor

Tags: primefaces, text-editor, google-font-api

Does anyone know if I can add more Fonts **(Including Google Fonts)** to the Primefaces `textEditor` component.

The Primefaces showcase and the implementation of the `textEditor` only has three components available.

> https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml

Answer (score 2):

1. Example how to add custom fonts to QuillJS which is the library 
   TextEditor uses: https://quilljs.com/playground/#custom-fonts
2. It is currently not possible with PF to register your own QuillJS modules with the PF component. I suggest you request an enhancement on the PF page here: 
   https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues